# How can you use a public group in a conga composer's button URL field? (Like a merge field)

Tags: workflow, custom-button, conga, merge-field

I'm using conga composer with conga workflow.

And I'm trying to send an email using the conga parameter &EmailAdditionalTo="emailid@something.com"

Is it possible to address the email to a public group I have in salesforce? Is it possible to use it like a merge field?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The &EmailAdditionalTo parameter requires a value of either A) a single email address or B) multiple email addresses separated by commas.  Your requirement can be accomplished by using a SOQL Query (available to be used with Conga Composer by using a free add-on) to query Group Member email addresses.  You'd then use the &QVar parameter to reference your query in your button URL, format the query string result using &QVar0Format, and pass the result to the &EmailAdditionalTo parameter.

Your eventual SOQL query might look something like this:

SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Id IN (SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE Group.Name = '{pv0}')

In this case, the dynamic value for '{pv0}' would be a Group Name that you could pass in your Composer button URL.  The parameters in your corresponding button URL would look like so:

**&QVar0Id=a03i000000CGeFQ?pv0=Test+Group**

**&QVar0Format=10000**

**&EmailAdditionalTo={QVar0}**

I got this to work just fine in a Dev org.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Whoops, I should also clarify that the &QVar0Format code of '10000' will insert a comma between the email address values that are returned by the SOQL Query

Comment: this is brilliant; I had forgotten about QVar -- so many Composer parameters to keep in mind :-)

Comment: Thank you so much Robert! I will check it out. It's amazing that we can do so much using Conga products :)

Comment: You're very welcome! Those QVars can be pretty powerful.

Comment: Just tried it out end to end in prod, it works. Thumbs up!

Comment: Great news Prabhat!